# Insert a Text() if a Grid List is Empty in Flutter

Tags: list, flutter, grid, future

I'm developing a Flutter app and in my `Main` route, I have a `Grid List`, populated with elements retrieved by a DB. 
When the Grid is empty I want to layout a `Text()` message, or something like that,
**permanently**.
I populate my List with

```
list() {
   return Container(
      child: FutureBuilder(
        future: pets,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.data == null) {
            return emptyGrid();
          }
          else
          return imageGrid(snapshot.data);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

Where emptyGrid is

```
Container emptyGrid() {
    return Container(
      child: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text("No Data Found")
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Problem is, `emptyGrid` is correctly laid out but disappears immediately after.

Comment: It sounds like your database is coming back with data. Have you printed out the value of the snapshot?

Comment: you have to do that in `Widget build` method

Comment: @EricDuffett I print. My DB is empty. "No Data" is laid out but for just a second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify your `list()` as follow:

You need a check if the list length is zero.

```
list() {
  return Container(
    child: FutureBuilder(
      future: pets,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.data == null) {
          return Text('Loading.....');
        } else if (snapshot.data.length == 0) {
          return emptyGrid();
        } else {
          return imageGrid(snapshot.data);
        }
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
      child: new FutureBuilder(
          future: FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("table").once(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              if (snapshot.data!=null) {
                return new Column (
                  children: imageGrid(snapshot.data),
                );
              } else {
                return Container(
                  child: Center(
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text("No Data Found")
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }
            }
          }
        )
      );
  }
```

Comment: I put it inside a Widget, but there is again the problem!

Comment: Same of before: Text("No Data Found") is laid out just for a second, doesn't remain on the screen

Comment: Have you tried the above code in your build method? and after that what screen shows?

Comment: yes. shows "No Data Found" for a sec and after that, disappears.